# how to set action in jquery texteditor?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set keydown action for jquery text editor.
**This is my html code.**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <textarea name="message" id="editor" onfocus="removeError();"      class="message-editor form-control" value="" placeholder="Type your cureent status"></textarea>
    <span class="message-error error help-block">   </span>
    @if($errors->has('message'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>
            {{$errors->first('message')}}
        </strong>
    </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$('input[name=template]').on('change',function(evt){
            if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
                $('#message-template-div').show();
                $('.save-template-div').hide();
            }else{
                $('#message-template-div').hide();
                $('.save-template-div').show();
            }
        });
```

so far I had tried by the id name and class. I tried for other text box with the same code. It worked for other but i can find the way for jquery texteditor.

Comment: `input[name=template]` shouldn't it be `input[name=message]`

Comment: also, change `on('change') ` to `on('keydown') `

Comment: It didn't worked.

Comment: `$('#editor').on('keyup',function(evt){
  alert(evt)
}`

Comment: No response. Didn't worked.

Comment: I think your js is not being called

Comment: yes. But why I don't know. every thing seems fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168893/discussion-between-sravan-and-binod-paneru).